# postgres join "other" table on "main" table that has 2 references to "other" table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following db schema:

```
messages
  senderId: user
  receiverId: user
```

I'm trying to fetch all messages with both the sender user and the receiver user records attached but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Before hitting the database, I fetch all messages for the logged in user by using his user id:

```
GET /messages?userId=some-id
```

my sql query:

```
SELECT * from messages
WHERE senderId=userId
OR receiverId=userId
```

I think I know how to do a join to get the user if it's his id:

```
SELECT messages.*, users.* from messages
INNER JOIN users ON messages.senderId = userId OR messages.receiverId = userId
WHERE senderId=userId
OR receiverId=userId
```

but I don't know how to join the 'other' user for the message. I also don't know if the query I'm attempting above will work because I haven't tested it yet.

Thank you for the help

Basically, I want all the data for the message record, and all the data for the 2 associated users (json, not sure how to express this as a column):

```
message: {
 title: 'message title',
 body: 'message body....',
 sender: {
  name: '',
  email: '',
  etc...
 },
 receiver: {
  name: '',
  email: '',
  etc...
 }
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: @GordonLinoff coming right up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to get the two names?

```
select m.*, um.name as sender_name, ur.name as receiver_name
from messages m join
     users us
     on m.senderid = us.userid join
     users ur
     on m.receiverid = ur.userid
where @userid in (m.sender_id, m.receiverid);
```

Comment: I want the whole record if possible, not just the name

Comment: @duxfox-- . . . Choose whatever columns you want.

Comment: can I use a star syntax? how would that look

Comment: You can.  Normally, though, you would choose the columns and give them different aliases so you can distinguish between the sender and receiver columns.

Comment: I see, I will work with this then, thank you for the help